# How to run a shell script in another user without typing password

Tags: linux, shell

I'd like to automate one job in hudson, but hudson always uses the user `hudson` to run the scripts.  What I want is to run the script as another user.

I've looked through ServerFault answers, but only found a solution that uses the `su` command, which requires me to type in  target user's password.  This will not work for automated scripts.

Could anyone help with this one? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `sudo` to do this.  First, you need to modify the `/etc/sudoers` file to add a rule that allows the `hudson` user to become the other user for the script in question.  Let's assume you have a `user1` account that needs to run `/usr/local/bin/my_script.sh`.

Run `visudo` to modify the `sudoers` file, and add a like like:

```
hudson ALL=(user1) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/my_script.sh
```

Then, use the following `sudo` command to run the script from hudson:

```
sudo -u user1 /usr/local/bin/my_script.sh
```

It's **very** important that you use `visudo` to modify the `sudoers` file in order to check the file for errors before putting it in place.  Also, I'd suggest a quick read through `man sudoers` in order to clearly understand what the above does before adding it to your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Commenting the `Defaults requiretty` entry in `/etc/sudoers` or other included suders files should help.

As for the perl error - your're probably using a different PERL5LIB or a different perl binary for that user - and that won't get passed in sudo (unless you use -E or env_keep). Check your environment and possibly, permissions.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo -u hudson command` will run command as user hudson.  It needs to be setup in your sudoers file, where you can also configure it to not require a password.